# How to resize an image on a website using css

Tags: css

I have an image which is 1400px by 660px and would like it to cover the full width and height of the browser's window without it having to scroll beyond the viewport. How can i achieve this using css to control the dimensions?

Comment: can we crop the overflowing part of the image ? otherwise it will get stretched

Answer (score 2):

```css
body{
margin: 0;
}
img{
min-width: 100vw;
min-height: 100vh;
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/1400/660/nature/" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#myImg{
    position:fixed;
    top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
}
```

with HTML:

```
<img id="myImg".... >
```

This will "stretch" the image to fit the screen.. If you would like to keep the proportions of the image I would recommend replacing it with a `div` with the image as `background-image` and `background-size` set to `cover`.